# How to loop category name from Custom Post Type to view on page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to loop category from plugin Custom post type. Ex: I create Custom Post type name: Player
[Click here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbq3v.jpg)
And I add that category into menu. That menu I already add more function already.And Then, I want to call all category that I create to show in page as Tap style and when click on category it will show the result. Ex: I have Category as Tap (Partner 1, Partner 2, Partner 3....) so when I click on Category Tap partner 1, it will show data of partner 1. Please see the image for more detail.
[U can click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tf8K.jpg)

Comment: Team1 , Team2 and ec is a category or post? And All members in each team is from custom post no?

Comment: Okay... waiting for your details....

Comment: Bhumi Pate: Title Team1, Team 2 and ec are Category that I select from Custom field. and img Profile and name, they are from post. and now I want to loop Category partner from Post Type Player as Tap menu to show in view like image above. and Other team 1 or Team 2 also I want to let user just select on Category Team1, or Team2 it will show auto. cos currently I need to write it again and for select team.

Comment: Now currently I want to know the code how to call category as Tab that I already create in CPT Player and click on it no reload to other page, and user can add more category too. I want it as dynamic,

Comment: It is my first time that doing on it. I feel complicated. and I am new learning about Advance custom field and Custom Post Type (CPT)

Comment: My problem that I need to solve is: I have Tap Partner 1,2,3,4.... and when we click on each Tap it show data from team, that all team I want to auto as post  no need to select it in code. cos now I am calling all team as category_name=>'team_category' (Ex: I have category team1 when I want to view team1 I need to write code to call it category_name=>'team-1'). Ex: I have category team1, team 2 so when I view it in page, i need to write code to view it, so do you have other solution for user that they just select category on Admin, no need write code?

Comment: I have two problem to solve it. If you don't clear some part please ask me back.

Comment: Sure... give some time... I'll try and share you code shortly....

Comment: okay thank you! I hope I can get solution from you.

Comment: Hi, Bhumi Patel, what is your solution now?

Comment: Why you added category in ACF? You can use category or subcategory instead of ACF....

Comment: Okay, tell me the easy way.